# "Request.Cookies ("iduser"). Value" equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application in VB.net and I'm doing a new one in C# (ASP.NET 4). Users has just one username to login in both app.

The point is... how can I get the cookie's value in C#???

This is how I get it in VB...

```
IdUser = Request.Cookies("iduser").value
```

Thks

Answer (score 2):

`string IdUser = Request.Cookies["iduser"].Value;`

Comment: @Thiago: What do you mean by assembly?

Comment: Sorry...The assembly reference. Like..."using System.Collections.Generic"

Comment: System.Web namespace should be all you need.

Comment: What's the context in which this code is placed?  I assumed it was on an ASP.NET page.  If it's elsewhere, you may need to do 
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies...

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["iduser"];
```

Or as the others say:

```
string cookie = Request.Cookies["iduser"].Value;
```

Depending on how you want to manage your cookie you can use either one.
[More on HttpCookie here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of app this is ?

ASP.NET I guess?

```
Request.Cookies["iduser"].Value
```

Works I think

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var str = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["iduser"].value;
```